# Opening Universal App Links in app doesn't link to the app

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I got deep links working in my app, so that when a users clicks on a deep link from, say, their messaging app then it works.

However if I have a link within my app (i.e. intercom) it seems to forget and just links it straight to Safari. Is there a way to catch in-app deeplinks?

Comment: You can override user activity in your app and handle the deep link logic there. See more [here](https://www.donnywals.com/handling-deeplinks-in-your-app/)

Comment: What do you mean by intercommunication? Are you having 2 diff apps of yours that are opening each other on clicks?
Or do you only have a single app in which there is some UI where you can click on your links?